# How to determine the probability density function of the length of various fishes

Tags: probability

Suppose I go fishing and catch a lot of fishes. I measure the length of various fishes and am interested in finding the **probability density** function **p(x)** where **x** represents the length of a fish.

Please note: The process of catching fish is continuous. Values of lengths are NOT discrete and can be any positive real number.

Also, the number of features (like length) can increase like 'width', 'fish eye color' etc.

So how to find the **joint probability** of various pair of feature,
example: joint probability: **p(l,c)** where l $\ge$ length; c $\ge$ eye color of fish.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: For a single feature draw the histogram and hopefully that will suggest a standard distribution, say log normal or whatever. Now fit your data to that distribution using maximum likelihood for instance and test to see if it is a good fit. For joint distributions you may need a lot of fish. I guess start looking for correlations between features first.